# How to display live logs from file in flask?

Tags: javascript, flask, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to display live data from my log file on webpage.

**GetLogs.js:**

```
var latest = document.getElementById('latest');
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', '{{ url_for('stream') }}');
xhr.send();
var position = 0;

function handleNewData() {
        var messages = xhr.responseText.split('\n');
        messages.slice(position, -1).forEach(function(value) {
            latest.textContent = value;
            var item = document.createElement('li');
            item.textContent = value;
            output.appendChild(item);
        });
        position = messages.length - 1;
}
console.log(xhr.responseText)
var timer;
timer = setInterval(function() {
    handleNewData();
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            latest.textContent = 'Ok';
    }
}, 1000);
```

**main.py(flask):**

```
@app.route("/stream")
@login_required
def stream():
    def generate():
        with open('system.log') as f:
            while True:
                yield f.read()

    return app.response_class(generate(), mimetype='text/plain')
```

**Html:**

```
<div style="overflow-y:auto;margin-right:20%;height:500px;width:500px;" class="center">
         <p>State <span id="latest"></span></p>
         <ul id="output"></ul>
</div>
```

**Error:**

*https://192.168.110.215/stream net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200* on `xhr.send()` And **xhr** returns **0**, so nothing appears on the screen.

I'm using self-signed cert for https.